# Dynamically create ContextMenu in Silverlight 5

Tags: silverlight, contextmenu, silverlight-5.0, silverlight-toolkit

I have just started to use Silverlight this few days.

Currently I have generated some panel dynamically in a canvas. Each panel will have a shared `MouseLeftButtonUp` event which will display a `ContextMenu`.

The problem now is when I click on a first panel, the ContextMenu is able to show but when I click on a second panel, the first ContextMenu shown up instead of the second. The second panel will show its ContextMenu only when I click another time on the second panel.

Below is my code to generate the panel and the context menu:

```
void generatePanel()
{
    StackPanel panel = new StackPanel();

    panel.MouseLeftButtonUp += panel_MouseLeftButtonUp;

    canvas.Children.Add(panel)
}

void panel_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;

    ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu();
    menu.IsOpen = true;
}
```

Hopefully my problem is clear enough. Is there any way to solve the problem? Or if there are any event that are fired when the menu is hidden, so that I can make sure the previous context menu is disposed or cleared?

Thanks.

Comment: How can they be different if you always call `new ContextMenu()`?

Comment: Since i call `new ContextMenu()`, aren't the previous data has no relation with the new contextMenu?

Comment: It should create a new context menu, but I don't know where it will be attached. It is recommended to use `ContextMenuService.SetContextMenu`, though it works differently.